# Lightweight Music Player distro

Tags: distribution-choice, music-player

Is there a lightweight Linux distro exclusive for reproducing music files? I'm looking for hte music equivalent to JustBrowsing Live CD.
I'm not really interested in music editing and whatnot. All I need is a music player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard of [AV Linux](http://www.bandshed.net/avlinux/)? It is an Ubuntu-based multimedia Linux distribution. It is designed for multimedia (Audio, Video, Graphics, etc) development and showcasing. Since you are mostly concerned with the playback of the audio, some basic tweaks and removal of software can significantly free up disk space. There are both 64 bit and 32 bit ISOs available.